# How to remove the dot on keyboard in WP 8.1 when the InputScope is Number

Tags: keyboard, windows-phone-8.1, inputscope

In WP 8.1, I have a `TextBox` whose `InputScope` it set to `Number`. (`InputScope="Number"`) However, this comes with a dot and I'd like to be able to remove it from the keyboard. I'd like the keyboard to have numerical values only as well as the backspace (clear) button.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to alter the keyboard that specifically. You can set the keyboard for numbers but not specifically for integers. You'll have to filter the results as they are received (you need to do that anyway since text could be pasted). The TextChanged event is a good place to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Would be cool to add this capability in the future. I know WhatsApp on iOS has an integer only keyboard when typing in phone numbers; however, I'm not sure if this is a custom user control or not.

Comment: Just found out both iOS and Android have numeric and decimal pads whereas only decimal is available for WP. Would love to see feature compatibility between all platforms.